# array matching and display in php

Tags: php, arrays, pattern-matching, matching

i am using PHP scripts to implement this...

```
    $keyword=array('local news','art','local','world','tech','entertainment','news','tech','top stories','in the news','front page','bbc news','week in a glance','week in pictures','top stories');

   //$keyword has predefined array of strings

    $all_meta_tags=get_meta_tags("http://abcnews.go.com/"); 
    $array=$all_meta_tags['keywords'];//store 'keyword' attribute values in $keyword_meta
```

Now i have to match contents of $array with $keyword.....the results should give me matched items of $array which are present in $keyword

### any help plz...?

can array matching/intersection be done case insensitively??
i mean if 
$keyword=array('local news');
$array = 'Local News, International News';
var_dump(array_intersect(preg_split('/,\s*/', $array), $keyword));

then it won't match 'Local News'...can you tel me hw to do it if it is possible??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$inBoth = array_intersect(preg_split('/,\s*/', $array), $keyword);
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/dy8dBjPh).

`get_meta_tags()` just returns the keywords as a string, so we need to split it into an array. We take into account people adding spaces, newlines or tabs after the `,`.

You could also skip the regex, and explode on `,` and then use `array_map('trim', $array)`.

Without doing this, you run the risk of `"art"` and `" art"` not matching.

#### Update

> can array matching be done case insensitively?

If you don't mind the resulting arrays being lowercase, you could use `array_map('strtolower', $array)` on both arrays before using `array_intersect()`.

Otherwise, this will do it...

```
$metaKeywords = preg_split('/,\s*/', $array);
$matches = array();
foreach($keyword as $keyword) {
  foreach($metaKeywords as $value) {
     if (strtolower($value) == strtolower($keyword)) {
        $matches[] = $keyword;
     }
  }
}
```

`$matches` will have keywords in both arrays case insensitively.

If you have multibyte strings, use `mb_strtolower()` or equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `array_intersect()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php